# Adding image in background into loop

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to insert image in the background of horizontal letter list (I mean each letter will get small image in the background), it's wordpress code.
the code:

```
   <?php
    foreach ($letters as $letter) { 
$url = add_query_arg('first_letter',$letter,$pageURL);
    echo "<a href='$url' title='Starting letter $letter' >[ $letter ]&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
} ?>
```

when I try to add:

```
  <img src="graybluetab.png" alt="" />
```

it's doen't stay horizontal and not in the background - it's display each letter in different line.
What can I do about, I tried to look for a relevat CSS code and I didn't find, Please help.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually , you can do it by applying the image as a background image like:

```
background:url(someimage.jpg);
```

After that you can repeat that image as you want.

```
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

**OR**

```
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

If you can simulate you code in Fiddle, we can help some more.....

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Can you please help me w/the arrangement:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkyNS/